# Is it possible to play DRM content in Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla on Raspberry pi ARM64?

Tags: firefox, chromium, raspberrypi, 20.10, drm

I am trying to use a Raspberry pi 4 as a standard desktop computer. After Ubuntu 20.10 installation, I was not able to play any DRM content on Firefox or Chromium.

With firefox, I already know that it's not possible yet : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1679354

With Chromium, I find several ways to activate DRM, but only on Raspbian. For example :
https://blog.vpetkov.net/2020/03/30/raspberry-pi-netflix-one-line-easy-install-along-with-hulu-amazon-prime-disney-plus-hbo-spotify-pandora-and-many-others/

Is there a way to do it with Ubuntu ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case other user gets same issue, here is what I have finally found :
https://github.com/monkaBlyat/docker-chromium-armhf

And maybe in (hopefully a close) futur Widevine will be supports in Ubuntu ARM :
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/03/raspberry-pi-os-gets-official-widevine.html

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post a solution to your problem.